# iTunes connect: App ID does not show in bundle ID dropdown menu

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-id

I created an App ID in the *Developer Portal* 
Then I create an new app, and hit the Bundle ID dropdown menu,
the App ID I created is not in the list there. It shows in the App ID section in the *Developer Portal* but not when I'm creating a new app.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[This first image, shows where the App ID should apear, after I have created it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZPcq.jpg)

[The second image, shows where I created the App ID and that it actually is there, the one that is not blurred all the way out, is the one. Its therem but it does not show, when I want to create an new app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmKyb.jpg)